# Loading a new ViewController programmatically

Tags: ios, segue

User opens the app and the LoginViewController is shown, once they enter their details and press the login button a NSURLRequest is made and if the result is success the app needs to load the HomeViewController.

Everything is working except for loading the HomeViewController.

I have tried instantiating HomeViewController and:

```
[self presentViewController:Home animated:YES completion:NULL]
```

But it doesn't load the new controller, I'm not sure if I need to segue or perform some other type of modal request I'm not aware of.

Comment: are you using a storyboard ? please post the code where you are creating home controller.

Comment: I'm using storyboards, all the controllers are created this way, I tried ctrl+drag from Login to Home, set as modal segue, add an id, call it with [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueName" sender:sender]; but nothing happens either...

Answer (score 1):

I assume `Home` is the class of the `HomeViewController`? 
It would be more of cocoa style when its name `was` HomeViewController.

```
self.homeViewController = [[Home alloc]init];
```

By doing so you would have to care for creating and layouting all the views that the controller contols. If you do that with Interface Builder then use

```
self.homeViewController = [[Home alloc] initWithXib:@"NameOfTheNibFileHere"]];
```

If your view controller is layouted in a storyboard, then give it an ID "HomeID" in this example) within the storyboard and load it via.

```
self.homeViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeID"];
```

If it is the root view controller of your storyboard, then I suggest to use

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
```

and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a segue, but you don't want to trigger the segue from your login button - you need to do it programmatically. In Image Builder, go to the bottom of your login view and control-click on the yellow View Controller icon in the black bar and drag to your `HomeViewController`.  Select "Replace" as the segue type and then give the segue an identifier (say "HomeSegue") as per usual.

Now, once your login has completed you can trigger the segue using

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"HomeSegue" sender:self];
```

If the login fails then you can stay on the login view controller and display an error as appropriate